# how to remove normalizedusername,twofactorenabled and few other column from table aspnetusers in c#

Tags: asp.net-core

Please help to know how to delete the below highlighted column from the table aspnetuser in c#
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RklH3.png)

Comment: Why do you want to remove them?

Comment: No,you can't do it.Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61391665/11398810).